# How to update an existing value in state array without mutation?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function to get currentStatus and id and change a value based on above parameters. I have following state.

```
this.state.column : [
  [
    arr1 : { id: 1, currentStatus: ''to-do'}, 
           { id: 4, currentStatus: ''completed'},
  ],
  [
    arr2 : { id: 10, currentStatus: ''in-progress'}, 
           { id: 14, currentStatus: ''completed'},
  ],
]
```

I'm giving new currentStatus and the particular id as parameters to the following function and need to replace the existing currentStatus with the new currentStatus. The particular object can be found by the id (which is unique for the whole array). **I'm trying the following code and finally getting the error `Cannot read property 'nn' of undefined`**

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

getCurrentStatus = (currentStatus, id) => {
    Object.keys(this.state.columns).forEach(ee => {
      if (this.state.columns[ee].find(x => x.id === id)){
        var nn = this.state.columns[ee].findIndex(x => x.id === id)
        this.setState({
          columns : update(this.state.columns, {ee:{nn:{$set : currentStatus}}})
        }, () =>
          console.log(this.state.columns)
        )
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where does `update` come from? Which library is that?

Comment: @RossAllen its from `import update from 'immutability-helper';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `ee` and `nn` variables are keys and index, so I presume that you want yo write an object with the values in those variables. So, your `update` call should look like this:

```
update(this.state.columns, { [ee]: { [nn]: { $set : currentStatus }}})
```

We use brackets to define keys with variables, like that:

```
const key = 'test';
console.log({ [key]: true }); // print: { test: true }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
And I had to set it as `update(this.state.columns, {[ee]:{[nn]:{currentStatus: {$set : currentStatus}}}})` to update only the currentStatus